# Android Studio unsupported version of gradle but I'm using a compatible version

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm using version 0.5.2 of Android Studio. I'm trying to import this project to my Android Studio [GCM SAMPLE](https://github.com/writtmeyer/gcm_sample)

But I get this error:
[image]

It says that I should use the version 1.10 of Gradle.

However, I am Indeed using that version.
[image]

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's giving you the wrong error message. The actual problem is that the project is using the wrong version of the Android Gradle plugin -- this project specifies 0.7, but Android Studio 0.5.2 needs 0.9.

In the project's top-level **build.gradle**, in this block:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
```

change the `classpath` line to:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
```

Comment: There's no buildscript block in the project's build.gradle
I Just tried to place it together with the other items in the dependency block. Like this: dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.0'
    compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.2'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}

But It still throws the same error

Comment: It's this file: https://github.com/writtmeyer/gcm_sample/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Oh yes, In the top level. Sorry. I'm gonna try it now

Comment: That `classpath` statement you put in your other `dependencies` block is wrong. Take it out.